# Inverse of Linear Operators - Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

"Suppose that $c$ is a real number, $c>0$, and for every $v$ in $V$, $v\neq 0$, and for every complex $k$, we have $\Vert T(v) - kv \Vert \geq c\Vert v \Vert$, where $T: V -> V$ is a linear operator. Then, for every complex $k$ the operator $(T - kI)$ is one-to-one, whence invertible, and for every $v$ different from $0$ we have $\Vert (T - kI)^{-1} (v) \Vert \leq \Vert v \Vert / c.$"

I've already proved injectivity and concluded that the operator is invertible, but I don't understand the inequality that involves $(T-kI)^{-1}$... I'm sure it is a simple thing, but I just don't get it. I'd appreciate if someone could help me!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec x = (T-kI)^{-1}\vec v$ for $\vec v \in V$. Then we know that $||(T-kI)\vec x|| \geq c||\vec x||$, so

$$||(T-kI)(T-kI)^{-1}\vec v|| \geq c||(T-kI)^{-1}\vec v||.$$ After a little bit of manipulation, we are done.